# powershell scriptblock not executing unless I use Wait-Job | Receive-Job

Tags: powershell, scope, jobs

Powershell script:

```
param (
    [string]$timestamp
 )

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($timestamp)
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $body = @{timestamp=$timestamp
    }
    $contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
    $headers=@{"x-shopify-topic"="data_warehouse_reconcile/reconcile_variant_info"}
    $netAssembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::GetAssembly([System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSection])

    if($netAssembly)
    {
        $bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Static,GetProperty,NonPublic"
        $settingsType = $netAssembly.GetType("System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal")

        $instance = $settingsType.InvokeMember("Section", $bindingFlags, $null, $null, @())

        if($instance)
        {
            $bindingFlags = "NonPublic","Instance"
            $useUnsafeHeaderParsingField = $settingsType.GetField("useUnsafeHeaderParsing", $bindingFlags)

            if($useUnsafeHeaderParsingField)
            {
              $useUnsafeHeaderParsingField.SetValue($instance, $true)
            }
        }
    }

    $response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://example.com/t.asp" -Method:Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  -Headers $headers -Body $body
    Write-Host $response
} -ArgumentList $timestamp
```

If I execute the script-block outside of the job, it works fine. Or, if I include

```
| Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

after the argument list, it works fine. Is there a scope issue here?

Comment: I will assume what you mean by "scriptblock not executing unless I use `Wait-Job | Receive-Job`" means that when you run the script without these cmdlets, the process just dies, if that's the case, this is expected, a job runs as a separated process (child process) in this case but if you dont wait for it to complete the parent process dies and so does the child

Comment: Ok. I was trying to execute a number of script blocks asynchronously and I thought this was the way to do it.

Comment: You __can__ execute asynchronously as long as the process still runs. In this case, seems like `Start-Job` wont help you at all. if you're doing this through a scheduled task, just don't use `Start-Job` it's pointless

Comment: Thank you. I was misunderstanding how powershell jobs worked.

Comment: Perhaps this question could be deleted since there is actually no issue in PowerShell it self?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would make a difference. If someone didn't understand threading in C#, for instance, would you remove the question because C# didn't have an issue? Questions here almost always involve someone's request for more knowledge, not bugs in the software itself. That's sort of the whole point here.